# Creating GoogleProgressbar in Android Application

Tags: android, progress-bar

I just want to create GoogleProgressbar in my application. I found zip file for it at following link :

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/368

But, confused in implementing it.

Is there any tutorial available for implementing GoogleProgressbar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0) Add to gradle project:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.jpardogo.googleprogressbar:library:1.2.0'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

1) add in xml file like this:

```
 <com.jpardogo.android.googleprogressbar.library.GoogleProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/google_progress2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

2) create array.xml and make your own colors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <array name="progressLoader">

     <item>@color/red.ufc</item>
     <item>@color/blue.ufc</item>
     <item>@color/gray.ufc</item>

    </array>

</resources>
```

3) In activity invoke your GoogleProgressBar:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    //ProgressBar mBar;
    GoogleProgressBar mBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        mBar = (GoogleProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.google_progress2);


        try{
            mBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(new FoldingCirclesDrawable.Builder(this).colors(getResources().getIntArray(R.array.progressLoader)).build());
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("mBar", "onCreate() returned: " + e );
        }

  }
```

In launch project your see GoogleProgressBar animation (loading).

The same thing for:

GoogleMusicDicesDrawable
NexusRotationCrossDrawable
ChromeFloatingCircles

good luck!